# Iphone game development switching between scenes

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have created a pause button on touch the scene is replaced by the pause menu....

and when we resume the scene comes back...however the function keep calling themselves....

how can i pause every thing in my current file when i switch to another scene...

Comment: Some code would be useful. Are you using UIViews or something else?!

Comment: Okay, dunno how cocos2d works, but I added the cocos2d tag so that someone with an idea about cocos2d sees this thread better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"on touch", the running scene should call:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: [PauseMenu scene]];
```

The pause menu's "back to game" button should then call:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene];
```

Pushing the pause menu into place, should "pause" the scene that is currently being pushed back and when you pop it back it should continue running.

Documentation: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_director.html